# Configure firewall to enable XAMPP working over LAN

Tags: xampp, firewall, lan

When I turn off the firewall, I can access my XAMPP website through other LAN computers.  When I turn on firewall then I cannot connect to the machine anymore.   Could someone tell me what's happening?

my os is windows xp.  thanks.

Answer (score 40):

Go to Control panel - > go to Windows Firewall -> then Advance Settings ->

1. Click Inbound Rules
2. right Click the inbound rules and select "New Rule..."
3. select option port and click next
4. select all local ports or your port number for apache server. and click next
5. select option allow the connection and click next
6. next
7. Give name Allow All Local Port For Xampp

Try This, I hope it will Work for you.

Comment: These instructions solved a similar problem in a Windows 10 environment running XAMPP v3.2.1

Answer (score 4):

I understand this is an old question and related to `Windows XP` but now for users using current OS like `Windows 10` the option that worked for me is that Inbound Rules Profile could be set to `Public` for `Apache Http Server` which is set to `Private` by default.

[image]

The profile could be set in 'Advanced' tab of `Apache Http Server` Inbound Rules properties as shown below (Properties Dialog box could be opened by Right Clicking on `Apache Http Server` and select Properties):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well , first of all, firewall on host is blocking your connection. If you are using Windows firewall or any other firewall You need to make an excaption rule for XAMPP.

So, on computer where is web site hosted go to Control panel-> Windows Firewall and uncheck *Don't allow exceptions* checkbox. Now open *Exceptions* tab and click on a button Add program and locate Xampp and Apache. Add them to firewall exception rule.

Maybe you should do this test on some Virtual Machine (VMware, Virtualbox..etc) **becouse opening ports and adding exceptions if this machine is connected to Internet** is not secure.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, (windows 10 and xampp v3.3.2)
1. Open Control Panel
2. Search for windows fire wall
3. Click Advance setting
4. Click inbound rules
5. Allow all blocked rule in name Apache HTTP Server and mysqld

[image]