# PHP MySQL localhost connection problems

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I changed my default port from 80 to 8080, but when I run localhost, I get below error:

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
Retry to connect
```

Comment: What are you using to run your mysql database? WAMP?

Comment: Mysql connect through 3306 port not 80 port. 80 is used for apache server

Comment: Hello MaartenDev, I am using Xampp

Comment: Hey Anik, sorry, the port I changed to 3307 since apache wasn't starting at 3306

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall an add a ingoing/outgoing rule for your XAMPP/WAMPP Application and allow all ports (Enable Checkbox).

Check this thread out, because your question seem to be similar: [Configure firewall to enable XAMPP working over LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192193/configure-firewall-to-enable-xampp-working-over-lan)

Alle the best!